# Duplicate emails receive via Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

Good Day.

We used hMailServer and one of our Employee is getting duplicate emails.
We're using Microsoft Outlook 2013 email client, configure our company email via imap. Is there any place in hMailServer management console to check to fix the issue?

Comment: If users exit Outlook client, do they receive duplicated emails on web mail? This helps determine whether this issue lies on client side or server side.

Comment: Assuming they're not receiving duplicate emails on the web side, so we can say that issue is on the client side, correct??

Comment: I found one link here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/eaa415e8-65f7-4474-a292-6839d80d3627/outlook-2007-crashing-and-receiving-duplicate-emails?forum=outlook   You may check Sally Tang's reply